# Get iterator from a container uniformly random from iterators that satisfy a predicate

Tags: c++, c++11, random, iterator

I have a container, and I'd like to choose an iterator that satisfies a predicate at random. If it helps to be specific, the container is a map.

Naively, I would say this:

`std::count_if` to get the number of elements in the range.

Choose a random number btwn `0` and `num_elements-1`.

Create a lambda to make a stateful predicate that counts up to the random number and only returns true then.

`std::find_if` with the lambda.

Will this work, and is there a better way? Alternatively, I could use count instead of count_if and regenerate the number if it fails the predicate. Could be useful if the predicate is mostly true I suppose, but wouldn't work well for my purposes.

Comment: Could you clarify "an iterator that satisfies a predicate at random"? An iterator over a container? What are the argument(s) to the predicate? What do you mean by an iterator that satisfies a predicate?

Comment: I imagine you have enough of an idea to craft a code test.

Comment: Edited title and thanks for the question edit. celtschk's answer looks right for what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trade memory for performance by storing all iterators for which the predicate is true in a separate container, and then use the random number to select the iterator from that. That way you need to iterate through the sequence only once (note, however, that you still need a forward iterator, as stored input iterators would be invalidated as soon as you move to the next element). For example:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Predicate>
  ForwardIterator random_iterator(ForwardIterator first,
                                  ForwardIterator last,
                                  Predicate pred)
{
  // store iterators to elements where the predicate is true
  std::deque<ForwardIterator> store;
  for (; first != last; ++first)
    if pred(*first)
      store.push_back(first);

  // if no element satisfies the predicate, return last
  if (store.size() == 0)
    return last;

  // get a random number in range [0, store.size())
  int rand = get_random_number(store.size());

  // return the corresponding iterator
  return store[rand];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks about right. Thanks for the template; looks like I might be able to play with this and get some interesting iterator searches out of this too.